# Cardinality/Relationship/Crows feet not showing on the diagram after reverse engineering

Tags: database-design, visio

I really need some valuable advices from you. Not sure where's the issue with MS Visio 2010.

My database contains more than 100 tables. When I executed the reverse engineering wizard in MS Visio 2010 a diagram is generated with details of all the tables and its columns, but I was expecting the relationship/cardinality/crows feet too but that was not to be. I have also made the necessary configurations in the "Display Options --> Databse Document Options"

Is there anything I am missing while generating the database model diagram?
Will appreciate a lots if someone Could please advice/help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue today. The solution is to clear the drawing and then drag the objects from the model back on to the drawing. At that time, the crow's feet notation will be shown. It appears that just changing the Display Options for already-drawn items has zero effect.

Please note that this reverse engineering function has been removed from later versions of Visio.

Comment: Thank you Timbuck & sorry for the late response, didn't checked inbox for ages.